# strange bug when trying to position <a> element

Tags: html, css

Basically I've got a div with a few anchor elements in it that need to be positioned along as a navigation menu.

The HTML looks fine and the CSS works for all the anchor elements except one, which refuses to be positioned normally, I could put the code down here but there is really nothing wrong with it.

I'll put it anyway :

**HTML**

```
<div id="navBar"><a id="home" href="Home.html">Home</a>
         <a id="a" href="#">a</a>
         <a id="b" href="#">b</a>
         <a id="c" href="#">c</a>
         <a id="d" href="#">d</a>
         <a id="e" href="#">e</a>
         <a id="f" href="#">f</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#home { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 160px; font-size: 18px; font-family: "century gothic", sans-serif; font style: normal; color: #2F4F4F; text-decoration:none;}
#a {position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 350px; font-size: 18px; font-family: "century gothic", 
sans-serif; font style: normal; color: #2F4F4F; text-decoration: none;}
#b { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 500px; font-size: 18px; font-family: "century gothic",
sans-serif; font style: normal; color: #2F4F4F; text-decoration: none;}
#c { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 650px; font-size: 18px; font-family: "century gothic", sans-serif; font style: normal; color: #2F4F4F; text-decoration: none;}
#d { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 800px; font-size: 18px; font-family: "century gothic", sans-serif; font style: normal; color: #2F4F4F; text-decoration: none;}
#e { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 950px; font-size: 18px; font-family: "century gothic", sans-serif; font style: normal; color: #2F4F4F; text-decoration: none;}
#f { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 1100px; font-size: 18px; font-family: "century gothic", sans-serif; font style: normal; color: #2F4F4F; text-decoration: none;}
```

It all looks pretty straightforward but for some reason the `<a>` element just won't move at all, it must be some kind of a but I haven't got any idea how to fix it.

Comment: can you give jsfiddle for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was the simplest thing, I had another element with the same name on the css style sheet.

ALWAYS CHECK THE SMALL STUFF FIRST.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use position on anchor elements unless you're doing something wildly unorthodox. You simply aren't comprehending CSS level 1. You need to apply `float` to the `div` elements...which you don't have.

Secondly you don't have child `div` elements, this is accessibility related. Add them, put the anchor elements in them and float the `div` elements with `width` as so...

Thirdly you're applying some wild amounts of space per menu item and from the home menu it's clear that you intend this to be a text-based menu.

Lastly if you're going to use an `id` for the menu you might as well use `nav` as it correlates to (X)HTML5's `nav` element.

**CSS**

```
#nav > div {float: left; width: 200px;}
#nav > div > a {display: block;}
```

**(X)HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
<div><a id="a" href="#">a</a></div>
<div><a id="b" href="#">b</a></div>
<div><a id="c" href="#">c</a></div>
<div><a id="d" href="#">d</a></div>
<div><a id="e" href="#">e</a></div>
<div><a id="f" href="#">f</a></div>
</div>
```

PS Unless you are clarifying the difference to someone about XHTML versus HTML then you have zero reason to use the terminology "tag", those are called elements. Using correct terminology will increase the effectiveness of your communication and create a better reflection of how people perceive your skills.

Comment: obviously I'm still a beginner, but thanks, i'll try putting them in divs, I still don't get how all the links behaved correctly and this one didn't though.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help, the div just acts the same as the <a> element, with the position not being affected.

Comment: Create a minimal test case, edit your post and then reply to my answer again and I'll modify my answer and reply. Otherwise it's a shot in the dark and someone may mark the question as being too vague.